# Node.js rest api with json and bigint properties

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

I'm quite new to node.js and I'm working in a rest api in which I'm having an annoying problem that I just can't wrap my head around.

This is the problem: the api recieves, via POST, a json object. Within this json object there are some properties that are bigint. Let me give you an example of these objects:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "appid": 730,
      "classid": "2222",
      "id": 99,
      "instanceid": "instanceID",
      "market_name": "Market name"
    },
    {
      "appid": 730,
      "classid": "2222",
      "id": 99,
      "instanceid": "instanceID",
      "market_name": "Market name"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Mensagem de teste",
  "user": 76561197960275584
}
```

In the server side the user property returns **76561197960275580**. It is a JS rounding problem and I have tried to solve it using many packages (bignumber.js, json-bigint, etc.. ) in total some 5 solutions and none have worked for me. I just can't use them because when the json object hits the server it is already with its int properties rounded. Let me put a piece of my node code here.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var api = express();

api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
api.use(bodyParser.json());

api.post('/import', function importEndPoint(req, res) {

    console.log('req.body.user=' + req.body.user);
});
```

When I console.log(req.body) the values are already rounded.

As I told, I've tried many libs to solve. I've read a lot of answers to problems like mine and still it doesn't work. I'm sure it is a newbie thing I'm missing but I just can't realize what it is.

Can you help me, please? The api uses express 4 and I can't change the json object to send these values with string.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your best bet is to probably buffer the posted data yourself, convert the bigint to a string, then parse it with `JSON.parse()`. Which means you'll probably have to write that middleware yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to make this field string then parse it your self otherwise you have to hack body parser, and change the way converting this field.

Comment: The question author already stated that this is not an option.

Comment: Thanks. I will be reading about this. Watching videos I saw that some people prefer another middleware instead of body-parser. I will be searching on these options.

Comment: @Freyday sorry I could not see that my answer, question author stated is not an option.